# Creating list of contours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have (x,y) points for contour lines (`cnt`). By comparing the data structure with that of `findContours` return value (`contoure`) I created list that looks almost identical.
`cnt` is list of 3D arrays and `contoure` is list of 3D arrays.

I get the following results:

```
len(cnt) = 140
len(contoure) = 140

cnt.shape = (20L,1L,2L)
contoure.shape = (20L,1L,2L)

np.size(cnt,0) = 140
np.size(contoure,0) = 140

np.size(cnt) = 5600
np.size(contoure) = 140
```

I don't understand why I get "tuple index out of range" for `np.size(contoure,1)` (note that `contoure[i]` is 3D array!) but no error with `np.size(cnt,1)` and why `np.size(cnt) != np.size(contoure)`.

I assume that drawContours doesn't work with `cnt` because of this difference, but I have no idea why this happens.

EDIT:
contour is created by findContours() call. I don't know exactly how cnt is created because my friend programmed that part of code, I only get the result in the following form:
all_cnt:

```
x11 x12 ... x1n
y11 y12 ... y1n
.
.
xm1 xm2 ... xmn
ym1 ym2 ... ymn
```

where x1,y1 are n pairs describing first contour. Than I use the following code:

```
cnt=[]

for i in range(140):
    a=all_cnt[2*i:2*i+2]
    a = np.reshape(np.ravel(a,order='F'),(20,1,2))
    cnt.append(a)
```

Comment: How are you creating either of `cnt` or `contoure`?

Comment: I edited my original post. My answer is in EDIT.

Comment: I found the solution. all_cnt has to be of type int32!

Comment: In that case, it is a good idea to answer your own question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and I overlooked the answer button. Thus I answered in comments. I will answer it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 3D arrays inside list of contours have to be of type int32. In my case I had to define all_cnt as all_cnt.astype(np.int32).

If you're not using findContours and you want to use drawContours(), contours parameter should look like this: list(array,array,...), where dtype of array is int32, and each array looks like this: [ [ [x1, y1] ], [ [x2, y2] ], [ [x3, y3] ], [ [x4, y4] ], ...  ].
Each array contains border points of 1 object.